# Live reload Angular4 app in Docker container?

Tags: angular, docker

We are deploying our production Angular4 webapp in a Docker container. Our Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update python \
                 python-dev \
                 py-pip \
                 nodejs \
                 nodejs-npm \
                 openssl \
                 nginx

RUN pip install jinja2

RUN npm -g config set user root
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN mkdir /app

ADD web /tmpbuild
WORKDIR /tmpbuild
RUN npm install
RUN ng build --env=prod
RUN mkdir /app/html
RUN cp -R dist/* /app/html/
RUN rm -rf /tmpbuild

ADD app /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod 755 start.sh

ENTRYPOINT /app/start.sh
```

Because we want our development environment to match our production environment, we are also containerizing our webapp locally, using this same Dockerfile. The question is - how do we keep the files compiled in development consistent with those in our production container, while also live-reloading? If we used `ng serve` instead of `ng build --env=prod` in the Dockerfile for development, then the live reloading would work as expected. But running `ng build` may fail when `ng serve` doesn't (for instance, using aot compilation prohibits the use of private variables in certain cases with `ng build` but not with `ng serve`), which is why we need the commands to be consistent between development and production.

Is there another recommended approach to achieve live-reloading with `ng build`?

Comment: You want to have your development environment match your production environment? I can't tell you just how much of a bad idea this is. Also having live reloading against production will be very slow.

Comment: @crooksey could you try to tell me? Seriously, I'm curious. Everything I've found so far suggests that it is a good thing (i.e. https://medium.com/travis-on-docker/why-and-how-to-use-docker-for-development-a156c1de3b24)

Comment: I think @crooksey point is that Live reload for local development is great. For production it would not be good as it would be more ram intensive, cpu bound, and slowier. Plus if you make a change mid request for someone it has the potential of causing issues.

Comment: @ShawnC. ah, ok I was unclear. I want live-reload in development but not in production. The hope was to find a way to get live reloading for development and also make sure that there are no surprising errors when we build for production, due to the differences between `ng serve` and `ng build`. I don't think there is a way to achieve this so we will just develop normally using `ng serve` and then build the production container to check our changes before merging.

Comment: Once initially configured, ng build should pickup errors not necessarily found by ng serve, not usually the other way round, so production builds should be more stable than development. The only other thing you can do, is run ng build after after development change, then fire up a Web server locally to serve the built application locally for testing, then once you want to ship it to production, do whatever you need to do to push the local code to your production server. Seems alien and counter productive to me, but if you want to develop against same code as production, this would work.